# how to copy the files from server to local pc in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, server, copy

I am trying to copy the files from the server to the pc. But I searched in google regarding this. I came to know that, I have to do ssh and so on. Is there any other way to copy the file from server to pc ?
Later I am using this file in my program.

Comment: I guess you have to find out, what kind of file transfer the server supports. There are different possibilities such as ftp, scp, etc.

Comment: I want to copy .log files from the server to PC

Comment: Yes, but do you know what the server supports? Is the server located i your LAN or only accessible via the internet? As you mentioned, the easiest way would possibly be scp. Why don't you use it? If you have a Windows PC you could take WinSCP which is easy to use.

Comment: server is accessible via the internet and I am using windows 7 O.S

Comment: You have to find out, what possibilities (ssh/scp, (s)ftp, etc) the server provides. If it is an external hosted server (by a provider) you may have access to a web interface where you can download the log files. That may be sufficient to get the log files from time to time. Otherwise you have to contact the provider or read the manuals. If it's a server which is administered by you or your company you have to ask your admin what you can do to get the log files.
If this post is about how to implement this in python you should ask again in a clearer way.

Answer (score 0):

You can scp(secure copy). It copies files from remote server to local using ssh. The basic syntax of scp is:
 `scp source_file_name username@destination_host:destination_folder`

For more options, you can check `man scp`.

Comment: is it possible for windows ?